# How to Deselect All Radio Inputs?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am using angular and have a radio input like this (in a form, if it matters):

```
<input type="radio"
       name="inputName"
       id="someId"
       data-ng-value=true <!-- This select "true" for my ng-model when clicked-->
       ng-model = "nameOfMyVarIn$scope"
       ng-change = "thisRunsWhenSelectionIsmade(true)"
       required></input>
```

I want to clear this input. Clearing the variable bound to ng-model clears the variable, but not the checkbox. I can't find how to clear the radio button itself [in the docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/input/input%5Bradio%5D) or in [random articles](https://scotch.io/tutorials/handling-checkboxes-and-radio-buttons-in-angular-forms) - it stays selected. I made a quick copy of the example from the docs and added `$scope.clearSelection` - the goal is to have this function de-select the selected input. In the real application I have other inputs in the form, so I can't just clear the whole form.

[Plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/dPPheHG6YJ388gWLWA7H?p=preview)

Comment: Call `.reset()` on the form element.

Comment: Thanks, so basically $scope.nameOfForm.nameOfField.reset()? nameOfForm being the value of the form's name attribute.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using your Plnkr, I've set `color` to `null` and it cleared the value. Is this what you want?

```
$scope.clearSelection = function(){
    $scope.color = null;
}
```

Here is the [updated Plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/6knYiOpSv7PNwKdukRWr?p=preview)

Comment: You answered the question. It doesn't work in my project, but that's my problem until I figure out how to replicate the issue in plnkr better. Appreciate it regardless.